# PHP Upload Multiple Images While Inserting Multiple "Select" Data Into Mysql

Tags: php

I have an image upload page with the following:

A multiple select box which has 9 categories listed.
A text input field of what the image alt text will be.
A multiple file upload field.

The goal is to be able to upload multiple images at once, store the text input for the alt text with each, and also store any of the selected categories with each.

The script I wrote isn't necessarily failing since the error I'm getting is the one built into the script `Sorry, there was a problem uploading your images.`.

The entire page is here:

```
<?php 
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/settings/functions.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/settings/config.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/top-notification.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/nav.php');
?>

<div class="container">
<?php
// Connect to database
$conn = getConnected("lucycypher"); 
// Don't execute upload script unless "upload" is clicked
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    // This is the directory where images will be saved
    $target = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/gallery/";

    // This gets all the other information from the form
    $img_category = implode(',', $_POST['img_category']);
    $img_name = $_POST['img_name'];

    // Count the image files
    if(count($_FILES['img_file']['tmp_name'])) {
        // Loop through each file
        foreach ($_FILES['img_file']['tmp_name'] as $img_file) {
            // moves the image
            if(move_uploaded_file($img_file, $target)) {
                // if upload is a success query data into db 
                mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO gallery_img (img_name, img_category, img_location) VALUES ('$img_name', '$img_category', '$img_file')") ;
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success margin-top">Your imags were successfuly uploaded.</div>';
            }
            else {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger margin-top">Sorry, there was a problem uploading your images.</div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Upload Image</legend>

<!-- Select Multiple -->
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="img_category">Category</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
            <select id="img_category" name="img_category[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
                  <option value="horror">Horror</option>
                  <option value="occult">Occult</option>
                  <option value="goth">Goth</option>
                  <option value="industrial">Industrial</option>
                  <option value="fashion">Fashion</option>
                  <option value="fetish">Fetish</option>
                  <option value="avante-garde">Avante-Garde</option>
                  <option value="cosplay">Cosplay</option>
                  <option value="nude">Nude</option>
            </select>
      </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="img_name">Name:</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="img_name" name="img_name" type="text" placeholder="Image Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">

      </div>
</div>

<!-- File Button --> 
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="img_file">Image</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="img_file" name="img_file[]" class="input-file" type="file" multiple>
      </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit">Ready?</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
      </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>


</div>

<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/footer.php'); ?>
```

And my database layout is:

```
ID              mediumint(10)   AUTO_INCREMENT
img_name        varchar(50)
img_category    varchar(200)
img_location    blob
img_time        timestamp       on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

When I select multiple categories, select an image file, and enter text into the text box nothing gets added to the database and the image does not upload to the server.

I just simply get the `Sorry, there was a problem uploading your images.` error.

My `gallery` directory does have `775` permissions.

Comment: Your target has to be a directrory:` $target = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/gallery/";` which can be correct  but you are adding the file you want to upload to your target so you don't have a target directory anymore. So you need to delete this line.
`$target = $target . basename($_FILES['img_file']['tmp_name']);`

Comment: Deleted it. Retried the upload. Same results.

Comment: Why the datatype of `img_location` column is `blob`? You're uploading files in the server anyway?

Comment: I read an article on uploading multiples and it recommended using `blob`.

Comment: @JesseElser I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few flaws in your code, such as:

- Look at this line here,

  ```
  if(move_uploaded_file($img_file, $target)) { ...
  ```

  `$target` should be a string specifying the destination file name, it should not be a directory path.
- Since you're uploading images in the server, there's no point saving them in the database as well. Simply upload the images in the server and save the paths in the database. So, change the datatype of `img_location` column to `VARCHAR`.

Overall, your code should be like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $count = count($_FILES['img_file']['name']);

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i){
        $target = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/gallery/";
        $target = $target . basename($_FILES['img_file']['name'][$i]);

        $img_category = implode(",", $_POST['img_category']);
        $img_name = $_POST['img_name'];
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img_file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target)){
            mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO gallery_img (img_name, img_category, img_location) VALUES ('$img_name', '$img_category', '$target')") ;
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success margin-top">Your imags were successfuly uploaded.</div>';
        }else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger margin-top">Sorry, there was a problem uploading your images.</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This did solve one problem. The image now uploads. However none of the information was entered into the database.

Comment: @JesseElser Ah, there's one mistake on my part. My first point of the answer is wrong, it should be `$img_category = implode(",", $_POST['img_category']);`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Now the data is being entered however when I try to upload two images for some reason the second one attaches the first ones name to it.

I.E. If I upload an image called `house.jpg` and one called `car.jpg` at the same time for some reason `car.jpg` gets renamed to `house.jpgcar.jpg`.

Although I will be updating this script to rename files to the textbox anyways once I figure that out.

For example if I put in the text box `Images Of Sunset` then any images uploaded with that text will be renamed `Images_Of_Sunset.jpg` and `Images_Of_Sunset_2.jpg`.

Comment: @JesseElser That's because of this line `$target = $target . basename($_FILES['img_file']['name'][$i]);`, the previous `$target` value get appended in the current iteration of the loop. Simply place this statement `$target = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/gallery/";` inside `for` loop and you won't see such behaviour. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for all the help.